# I am facing Issue in Inserting the Data in the Table

Tags: plsql

```
INSERT INTO aftmm_trans_content_rq
(project_id, rq_sno, stnd_key, locale_cd, clssf_cd, seq, "content", content_xpln, trtr_id, trt_dtm,trans_verify_yn)
VALUES('META',' 203','DESC-00026','ko_KR','DESC ','1','27011041-Korean','test00','20220127141206','Y');
```

I am getting the SQL Error as

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions  Position: 127

Comment: Which database do you use? PL/SQL tag means Oracle, but error you posted  doesn't look like Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, database doesn't lie about it.

```
INSERT INTO aftmm_trans_content_rq (project_id,         -- 1
                                    rq_sno,             -- 2
                                    stnd_key,           -- etc.
                                    locale_cd,
                                    clssf_cd,
                                    seq,
                                    "content",
                                    content_xpln,
                                    trtr_id,
                                    trt_dtm,
                                    trans_verify_yn     -- 11
                                    ) 
     VALUES ('META',                                    -- 1
             ' 203',                                    -- 2
             'DESC-00026',                              -- etc.
             'ko_KR',
             'DESC ',
             '1',
             '27011041-Korean',
             'test00',
             '20220127141206',
             'Y'                                        -- 10
             );
```

You're inserting 10 values into 11 columns, and that's a **mismatch**.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided **More(11)** fields while giving **less(10)** values respectively, and hence the DB error.

**Please remove a field from field list which you think is going to be set my default or add the appropriate value.**